# Using PageMethods with jQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery, pagemethods

Simply put I want to call *public static* methods decorated with *WebMethod* attribute inside my code-behind C# file from *jquery.ajax* to get some json and other simple stuff (in different functions). But instead I'm getting whole page :'(

I'm not using asp.net AJAX though I'm developing for .NET 3.5 framework and using VS 2008. (There are some restrictions from client)

Please let me know if I can use page-methods with using asp.net ajax or If not what is other simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much deliberations I found the problem. I was using [jquery's editable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable). This was source of the problem. When jeditable calls jquery's ajax it sets ajax options like this:

```
    var ajaxoptions = {
        type: 'POST',
        data: submitdata,
        url: settings.target,
        success: function(result, status) {
            if (ajaxoptions.dataType == 'html') {
                $(self).html(result);
            }
            self.editing = false;
            callback.apply(self, [result, settings]);
            if (!$.trim($(self).html())) {
                $(self).html(settings.placeholder);
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            onerror.apply(form, [settings, self, xhr]);
        }
    };
```

so it was sending the things as simple *html* and to use this with page methods we need to setup the things so that it sends as *json*. So we need to add something to the settings like this:

```
    var ajaxoptions = {
        type: 'POST',
        data: submitdata,
        url: settings.target,
        dataType: 'json', //Data Type
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //Content Type
       //....other settings
    };
```

So I put two new properties in settings **dataType** and **contentType** and changed above to this:

```
    var ajaxoptions = {
        type: 'POST',
        data: submitdata,
        url: settings.target,
        dataType: settings.dataType,
        contentType: settings.contentType,
       //....other settings
    };
```

Now another problem arised :( it was sending data (from **submitdata** property) as normal query-string which asp.net does not accept with *json* requests. So I had to use [jquery's json plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/LABSJSON) and change the way data is sent in ajax using following test on dataType:

```
    if (settings.dataType == "json") {
        if ($.toJSON) {
            submitdata = $.toJSON(submitdata); 
        }
    }
```

and it works like breeze!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but i think WebMethods are accessible only through asp.net AJAX. I may be wrong though, because we dont use it that way at all. We do it in a slightly different way.

We have built a aspx page which accepts all our AJAX requests and passes them to the subsequent methods.

**Server side code**

```
If Not (Request("method") Is Nothing) Then
            method = Request("method")
            username = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString
            Select Case UCase(method)
                Case "GETPROJECTS"
                    Response.ContentType = "text/json"
                    Response.Write(GetProjects(Request("cid"), Request("status")))
                    Exit Select
        end select
end if
```

**Client Side code [using jquery]**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(xhr, msg) { alert(xhr, msg) },
        type: "POST",
        url: "Ajax.aspx",
    beforeSend: function() { showLoader(el); },
        data: { method: 'GetProjects', cid: "2", status:"open"},
        success: function(msg) {
            var data = JSON.parse(msg);
            alert(data.Message);
        },
        complete: function() { hideLoader(el);  }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 @Vikram this one I've already tried, but it seems less elegant than using page methods. But think will have to go with this only. I'm using bit different version as I'm using this stuff with jquery.jeditable. Thanks for response.

Comment: yes, i know its not the ideal way but in absence of something more clean, have to work with this.

Answer (score 1):

Russ Cam posted this link in [response to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897408/asp-net-partial-page-upload-without-updatepanel-with-jquery/897464#897464) (so if this helps, go up vote his answer ;)):

> [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/)

Comment: @Zhaph I've already read that article and also follow his blog posts in my iGoogle homepage, but alas that is also about calling "Asp.net AJAX" page methods and I'm not using Asp.net AJAX.

Comment: @aman.tur - The post accomplishes the posts without ScriptManager - just jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Dave Ward has a series of [posts](http://encosia.com/category/jquery/) that use jQuery directly with ASP.Net PageMethods, no MS Ajax UpdatePanel required.  In particular this [post](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) will get you started.