# Why I don't get any tabs in simple demo using asp.net and jQuery UI?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I can't get my tabs working, no mater what I do. Demo is very simple and straight forward but i must missed something. 
CSS is applied and  `$("#pnlTabs").tabs();` function is called but nothing happens.

Please help me, this JS drives me nuts.

EDIT:

here is the link to zip file with complete solution http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12791555/HelpDeskControls.zip

EDIT2:

Just one more question. When You click "services" or "events" tab is it possible that function from codebehind is called ? Let's say that when I click on events tab, same function gets called that when I click on "Load" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that ID mangling might be the cause here.

Change your script to this and try again

```
$(function () {
    $('#<%=pnlTabs.ClientID %>').tabs();
});
```

Since the HTML specification requires element IDs to be unique within the DOM, the ASP.NET framework attempts to avoid the possibility of duplicate IDs appearing by rewriting the IDs that you assign to server controls in the page. If you think about it, this makes sense to some degree, as using controls such as the gridview for example, where you have a server control with an ID which you would like to repeat for each item in the datasource, you wouldn't want the ID to also repeat as this will result in invalid HTML.

Any control that is decorated with the [`INamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx) interface creates a new ID namespace which will result in element ID mangling on the client side.* Using the markup given above, we can have the ID that will be generated in the response sent to the client outputted into the page into the jQuery function call.

**ASP.NET 4 can be set to not mangle IDs, at your own peril!*

**EDIT:**

I've had a look through your demo code and all is working as intended - the tab event handlers are being bound correctly to the list elements which when clicked are applying the correct CSS classes to the div elements to show the corresponding one and hide the others, respectively.

It seems that you are missing a large chunk of the CSS required to style the tabs and it is the CSS classes that drive some of the tab behaviour. If you drop in a link to a jQuery UI theme CSS hosted on google api, then all appears to work correctly. I added the following after your CSS stylesheet link

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

and all appeared to work as expected.

On a side note, you may be interested in checking out ASP.NET MVC - in my personal opinion after using it for around a year, given a choice, I would not go back to web forms. If your comfortable with HTML, CSS and JavaScript, you might find it more intuitive than web forms to use :)

Comment: Are you shure ?
This is what I see with firebug.
<div id="pnlProcesses" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">

Comment: +1: Noting that ASP.NET 4 now supports static Client ID naming

Comment: Posted code here is simplified version of solution. So there is some differences, but I can't see error.
In the sollution I take into account that asp.net name mangling.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.
I hate HTML, CSS and JavaScript and I'm doing this because I must :( I'm more desktop app guy (C#, delphi, c++).

Comment: Just one more question. When You click "services" or "events" tab is it possible that function from codebehind is called ? 
Let's say that when I click on events tab, same function gets called that when I click on "Load" button.

Comment: yes it is possible to call a server side method (I assume you mean without reloading the whole page i.e. through AJAX) - the most popular way to do this in ASP.NET webforms is with page methods or web services. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897408/asp-net-partial-page-upload-without-updatepanel-with-jquery/897464#897464, since you're already using jQuery, you can use the `$.ajax()` method to accomplish this.

Comment: @Russ Cam
Thank you for link, I checked it and it is very interesting.
But for now I just want to call "protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" with all postback and page reloand and other stuff.

Comment: @Primoz - what you'll need to do in that case is have some way of letting the server know which tab was visible/ going to be visible when you postback so that the appropriate CSS classes can be applied to that list element in the response returned to the user. Perhaps the easiest way would be to use a hidden input control and change the value on the client side to the tab that will be visible on click of the list element.

Comment: Yes, but how to invoke this method "protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)" in the first place ?

Comment: You need to hook the method up to the click event of the BulletedList, the same way as you have done with the other buttons. On the client side, there should be some client script outputted to make this work, similar to `__doPostBack('OsControl_pnlTabs', 'index')` where 'index' will be the index of the list element clicked and gets bound to the `BulletedListEventArgs.Index` property on the server side in the event handler. What you might find with using jQuery tabs though is that they prevent the default action on the anchor element inside of each list item...

Comment: as the default action for an anchor element is to make a HTTP GET request back to the server. So to get this to work may require you to hook up the client side script manually, or not use the jQuery tabs plugin and handle all from the server side. The jQuery tabs plugin is designed to work more from a 'not needing to perform a full page postback to the server' point of view, which doesn't really map well when you want to it with full page postbacks.